# Unix/Linux: what is ./?

Tags: linux, command, ls

What is the `./` that you see on Linux if you do:

```
$ ls -a
./  ../ other-files
```

I know `../` represents the parent directory relationship, and I know that we can use `./` to execute files marked as executable, but what is `./` called and why does it show up in `ls -a` as a hidden file?

Thanks!

Comment: `.` is the current directory, `..` is the parent directory, `/` is the path separator.

Comment: Comments are for asking for clarification, not providing short answers.

Comment: If `./` is just the current directory, I guess my question then is why do we need to type `./` before an executable file in order to execute it?  If the file is in our present working directory, why not just the file name alone?  Thanks!

Comment: And why doesn't `echo ./` expand to our present working directory?  Thanks!

Comment: When you run an executable which isn't in a directory listed in your `PATH`, you need to supply its full name.  If you are in `/home/you` then you can say `./command` or `/home/you/command` equivalently.

Comment: `echo` does not manipulate its arguments in any way.  If you want to see what `.` refers to, try `stat .`

Comment: Read the documentation of [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) and [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). Your `ls` is aliased (perhaps to `ls -f`) in your shell, so try `/bin/ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.`  Refers to the current working directory. 
`..` Refers the parent directory of the current working directory.

***Directory Structure*** 
Every directory in Unix has a `.` and `..` as a reference. To understand it further check the `inodes` of `.` and `..` with `ls -lai` command .

Let say directory `a` is the parent directory for directory `b`. when you list the contents of directory `b` with `ls -lai` the inode of `.` will point to `b` directory and `..` will point to `a` directory.

***File Listing*** 
`.` and `..` can be used for file listing.

```
$ ls -l ./file1.txt
```

is same as

```
$ ls -l file1.txt
```

In the first case we have used with more specificity.

***File execution*** 
When we need to execute scripts that are in current working directory we do it with below methods.

`./` means execute `script.sh` which is present in the current working directory.

```
$ ./script.sh
```

we can pass `script.sh` as an argument to `bash` and so it is not necessary to specify `./`.

```
$ bash script.sh
```

or

```
$ bash ./script.sh
```

In case if the current working directory is part of `PATH` environment variable, then we can just simply invoke the script without mentioning `./` or `bash`

```
$ script.sh
```

`echo ./` will not get expanded because `.` is not special to `echo` or `bash`. Where as the file expansion meta characters like `*`, `?`, `..` and others are special.

Answer (score 2):

It is a node in the tree of the file system, and it show up because it has a file descriptor associated to it.

In the shell . represent the current directory and / represent that this is a directory and when we need to run a file we need to tell the path ./ like current directory and then the executable file.